# How to append default language to the URL loading for the first time in sitecore 6.2

Tags: sitecore

I made the languageEmbedding="always" in web.config file. However it is not appending the language to URL when the URL loads for the first time. For eg: http://www.abc.com/def/ghi

I need the URL to be similar as **http://www.abc.com/en/def/ghi**

Could any one suggent me the workaround for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`languageEmbedding="always"` only applies to links that are generated.
You must implement something on your own that forces the first request to be redirected if there is no language code present in its URL.

I think you can do that by adding a processor to the `<preprocessRequest>` pipeline and put it before the `StripLanguage` processor.

Answer (score 0):

Set the defaultLanguage="en" for the website node under  definitions.